# Have sudo create files under your own user id?

Tags: linux, permissions, python, sudo, ownership

If I wanted to do something like

```
sudo fdisk -l > test.txt
```

but I wanted test.txt to be under my own user ID (and not root) without having to chown it afterwards, is there a way to do this?

Specifically my actual goal is to have a python script perform a bunch of sudo-permission operations, and dump the outputs. In what way should I ask for sudo permissions if the flow is something like:

```
somescripts
 \-> runs python script, grabs sudo
      \-> runs operation with sudo permissions
      |     like fdisk -l > test.txt
      \-> runs operation with sudo permissions, reads stdout, writes stdout to file
            like fdisk -l --> reads stdout --> make file --> writes data to file
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tee`. What tee does is write stdin to a file and echo it on stdout too. Using it with a pipe and sudo effectively changes the active user for output redirection. Bear in mind that the left side of the pipe must actually write to stdout, not stderr.

```
sudo fdisk -l | sudo -u myuser tee <file>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sudo fdisk -l > test.txt
$ ls -l test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 daniel daniel 1848 apr 22 14:20 fd
```

It is not needed to change ownership of the file afterwards when using redirection like you describe.

When using `tee` as suggested, it is on the same premises not needed to use `sudo -u myuser`:

```
sudo fdisk -l | tee test.txt
```

suffices (but it is not needed in this case as per above demonstration).

---

In the context of the Python script, if you run the *entire script* as `root` via `sudo`, then the redirection will also be made as `root`, but if you just use `sudo` as in the earlier command-line example within the script, then it will behave as above.